# Proof of explicit formula for change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are given two sets of (not necessarily orthonormal) basis vectors {a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub>} and {b<sub>1</sub>,...,b<sub>k</sub>} of a nontrivial subspace of R^n. Define the matricies A, B to have their jth column be a<sub>j</sub> and b<sub>j</sub> respectively, and the change of basis matrix Q to be the usual one where b<sub>k</sub> is the sum over i of q<sub>ij</sub>*a<sub>i</sub>.

How can we prove that Q=(A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>T</sup>B ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $Q$,
$$AQ = B.$$
Left multiply by $A^T$,
$$A^TAQ = A^TB.$$
Now we need to show that $A^TA$ is non-singular. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent vectors (as, indeed, they form a basis), then $A^TA$ has non-zero determinant, and hence is invertible.

Therefore,
$$Q = (A^TA)^{-1}A^TB.$$